# how to Switch off Per row level subtotals dynamically for a Matrix in power bi

Tags: powerbi

We have Matrix where Per row level subtotal is Switched on for only one Row and for rest of the rows its turned off. Its good up to here.

Issue:- When a user adds a new column to the matrix then by default the subtotal is on for the newly added column. is there a way to dynamically turn off for the newly added columns ?

Answer (score 1):

We have to use `ISFILTERED` of any row context, example I have Date as rows in Matrix, I can use measure for `IF(ISFILTERED('Dates'[Date]),sum/values(that new column),blank())`.
this means we are restricting the newly added column to only row level data and total
of the matrix is converted to blank value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).